# Passing an instance of a class to a multiprocess in Python

Tags: python, multiprocessing, instance

```
   import multiprocessing
   import time

   def sleeper(sec):
   time.sleep(sec)

   if __name__ == "__main__":  
     sec=1
     process = multiprocessing.Process(target=sleeper,args=[sec])
     process.start()
```

---

The above code works well. However if the sleeper function is a method in an instance of class that doesn't work. So I need some ideas what should I do if sleeper function is an instant method (like below)

```
    class SleepingClass:
      def __init__(self, sec):
        self.sec = sec

      def sleeper(sec):
      time.sleep(sec) 

sleepingClass = SleepingClass(1)


if __name__ == "__main__":  
    sec=1
    process = multiprocessing.Process(target=sleepingClass.sleeper,args=[sec])
    process.start()
```

I tried running method not in instance class and it worked. But when I put it in instance class it did not.

Comment: You're definitely missing `self` in your method definition. Why do you try to pass `sec` as both class "constructor" (`__init__`) parameter and method parameter? This kind of defeats the purpose of class as a cohesive unit.

Answer (score 0):

The class wasn't written correctly.  Comments below in code:

```py
import multiprocessing
import time

class SleepingClass:
    def __init__(self, sec):
        self.sec = sec

    def sleeper(self):  # No need for "sec" argument.  Instance has it.
                        # But need "self" for instance method.
        print(f'sleeping for {self.sec} seconds...')
        time.sleep(self.sec) 

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Create the instance only in main
    sleepingClass = SleepingClass(1)
    # Pass it to the sub-process...no need to pass an argument.
    process = multiprocessing.Process(target=sleepingClass.sleeper)
    process.start()
```

Output:

```
sleeping for 1 seconds...
```

Comment: Thanks for your help I managed to drill down to my real issue:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77950220/python-class-instance-in-multiprocess-giving-error-when-it-contains-db-connectio