# Python Class Instance in MultiProcess giving error when it contains DB connection

Tags: python, oracle, multiprocessing, connection, instance

```
import oracledb
import getpass
import pyodbc
import multiprocessing

from datetime import datetime


def insertInOracle_worker(test):
    print(type(test))
    

if __name__ == "__main__":

    username="XXXXX"
    userpwd = 'XXXXX'
    host = "xxxxx.corporate.co"
    port = 1521
    service_name = "servicexxxx"
    dsn = f'{username}/{userpwd}@{host}:{port}/{service_name}'
    o_connection=oracledb.connect(dsn)
    #o_connection="Hello connection"
    list_of_columns= [['MEMBER_TYPE', 'CHAR',1]]
    oracle_import = Oracle_import(o_connection,"DISCOUNT_PROFILE",list_of_columns)      
    test = "ADRIAN"
    p1 = multiprocessing.Process(target=insertInOracle_worker,args=[oracle_import])     
    p1.start()
```

In the above code I get an error when I am connected to Oracle by o_connection and pass the class instance as a parameter for multiprocessing. If I comment it and remove the comment for  o_connection="Hello connection", then its all fine. Seems like pickling the connection is a problem. I am quite new to python and looking for suggestions.

I need to pass the my class for further purposes of background process.

Comment: What error do you get. Post the full traceback. Likely you need to open the connection in the process itself.

Comment: Server connections cannot be shared between processes.  Each thread needs to open its own connection.

Comment: Error: no default __reduce__ due to non-trivial __cinit__